# What all these parameters means in yoloV4 model

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo, darknet

What do all of these parameters from training YOLOv4 mean?

(next mAP calculation at 1300 iterations)

Last accuracy mAP@0.5 = 63.16 %, best = 68.55 %

1249: 26.351213, 24.018257 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 2.983998 seconds, 39968 images, 10.505599 hours left
Loaded: 0.000068 seconds

(next mAP calculation at 1300 iterations)
Last accuracy mAP@0.5 = 63.16 %, best = 68.55 %

1250: 13.904115, 23.006844 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 4.093653 seconds, 40000 images, 10.456502 hours left
Resizing, random_coef = 1.40

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the parameters mean.

For your given example:

```
(next mAP calculation at 1300 iterations) Last accuracy mAP@0.5 = 63.16 %, best = 68.55 %

1250: 13.904115, 23.006844 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 4.093653 seconds, 40000 images, 10.456502 hours left Resizing, random_coef = 1.40
```

- `1250` --> iteration
- `Last accuracy mAP@0.5` --> Last mean average precision (mAP) at 50% IoU threshold. mAP is calculated every 100th iteration. So, in the example, it's the mAP from iteration = 1200
- `best` --> highest mAP so far
- `13.904115` --> total loss
- `23.006844 avg loss`--> average loss, this is the thing you should care about for being low in training
- `0.001000 rate` --> learning rate
- `4.093653 seconds` --> total time spent to process the batch
- `40000 images` --> total amount of images used during training so far (iteration*batch = 1250 * 32)
- `10.456502 hours left` --> estimated time remaining for finishing up to the `max_batches` in your config file
- `Resizing, random_coef = 1.40` --> Confirming that your dataset is being randomly resized every 10 iterations from 1/1.4 to 1.4 (in this iteration, it's 1.40)

References:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-different-layers

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question. :)

Comment: @Addie Ira B. Parico Where could I find the log.txt file. I'm doing the training for yolov4 in custom dataset locally for multi-labels. The accurcy didn't report while training stage running. I use AlexeyAB Darknet repo in windows 11. How to get the accuracy for all classes. I appreciate any help.