# Darknet yolo v4 - how to get current learning rate?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, darknet, learning-rate

When I train yolo v4 with Darknet, few times a second I get a list of variables.
Is there an easy way to make Darknet binary also print learning rate?
If everything fails I will make changes in https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/detector.c and rebuild, but I'd really prefer to avoid maintaining a custom darknet version.

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data ../yolov4-custom.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map &> logs.txt & disown
```

```
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 139 Avg (IOU: 0.000000, GIOU: 0.000000), Class: 1.000000, Obj: 0.000000, No Obj: 0.000000, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 1, class_loss = 0.500000, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.500000 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 150 Avg (IOU: 0.394489, GIOU: 0.289983), Class: 0.985003, Obj: 0.004027, No Obj: 0.000896, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 6, class_loss = 3.253636, iou_loss = 0.891068, total_loss = 4.144704 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 161 Avg (IOU: 0.612244, GIOU: 0.555591), Class: 0.897004, Obj: 0.014743, No Obj: 0.000339, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 1, class_loss = 0.492179, iou_loss = 0.095293, total_loss = 0.587472
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The learning rate can be found in your `logs.txt` file

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66058498/14461262) for more information.

Comment: This only shows initial learning rate (which is usually 0, due to burn_in schedule for yolo-like networks).
What I'm after is tracking how lr changes during training.

Comment: I checked my own logs.txt (check this https://pastebin.com/5xZD0KQv). You will be able to see how the learning rate changes in the logs.txt file. For example. from the link I attached, it starts at "0.000000 rate" then changes if you scroll down.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which version of yolo are you using?
My logs look differently: https://pastebin.com/ptKz2LJ5 . 
But the "rate" variable actually appears there and I just missed it; I'll accept your answer.